# Self referencing relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently designing a contact management database as a rookie. I've encountered the following scenario:

I have created a table `company` for company information. Within the information I want to include the parent company, if they have one (for example: Ferrari is one of the company, but its parent company is Fiat, which is also one record in the `company` table).

I am not sure how I should approach this problem. Should I add a `parent_company` column to the `company` table and self-reference OR should I make a new table to store the parent-child relationship?

Comment: Both are fine.  Which to use depends on your use cases.  If 90% of companies have no parent, then the separate table will take less space.  If you want to query a very deep hierarchy without needing the other columns from the company table, using a separate table can be faster.  But, most of all, which feels like it will be easier to maintain?  That matters most to begin with...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend that you add parent_company (nullable) column in company table and reference it with company id. As I believe you are not gonna have multiple parent company for a sub-company, so no use of creating a new table. For many to many relationship you'd need a new table.

You can create foreign key reference like this

```
ALTER TABLE company ADD COLUMN parent_company INT UNSIGNED NULL, ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_parent_company REFERENCES company(id)
```

Use UNSIGNED if your table id has UNSIGNED attribute. Basically you have to follow exact column attributes for the new column, except make it nullable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Managing hierarchical data is tricky, particularly in MySQL which really has no built-in support.

If you knew in advance that almost all companies were singletons and here and there you had a parent company, then adding a `parent_company_id` to your table.

However, the situation can get more complex.  That is why I would suggest that you consider some alternatives on how to store the data.  For instance, it can be handy to store the entire hierarchy to the parent company.  [Here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) is a good article on storing hierarchical data.